Visualizing test report for multiple workflows using GitHub Actions and dorny/test-reporter v1
I have two separate workflows in a GitHub repository which run my test environment but with different versions of some dependent libraries. My goal is that each workflow runs the test environment and then visualises the results using the dorny/test-reporter@v1.
The workflows (simplified version) looks like:
name: Tests using version 1

on:
    pull_request:
      branches: ["main"]

    workflow_dispatch

jobs:
    run_tests1:
        # Some stuff needed to run the tests

        - name: Rename results to resultsVersion1
          run: mv results.xml results_version1.xml
          working-directory: .\folder\tests\

        # Upload artifacts but can probably deleted
        - name: Upload results for version 1
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
          with:
            name: resultsVersion1
            path: .\folder\tests\results_version1.xml

        - name: Report results for version 1
          uses: dorny/test-reporter@v1
          if: success() || failure()
          with:
            name: version 1 test results
            path: 'results_version1.xml'
            working-directory: .\folder\tests\
            reporter: java-junit
            list-tests: failed
            list-suites: failed

Workflow 2 looks similar but "version1" is replaced everywhere with "version2".
If make a pull request, both workflows start to run and pop up like:
Tests using version1 / run_tests1
Tests using version2 / run_tests2
Tests using version1 / version 1 test results
Tests using version1 / version2 test results
The problem I encounter is that the visualisation with the dorny/test-reporter@v1 always appears in the workflow where the tests are finished first (here "Tests using version1").
I would like to have the test visualisation to be assigned to the workflow that is actually executed. Does anybody has an idea why this happens?
